# Sacar objeto y ponerlo al inicio del array

Tags: javascript, html

Hola buenos días tengo una arreglo de objetos y lo que necesito es sacar el de la posición index y ponerlo al inicio del arreglo, este es mi código donde itero mi arreglo.

```
$.each(data.info_tarifas, function (index, value){
  if (value.id_tarifa == id_tarifa) {
     document.getElementById("combo_tarifa").innerHTML += "<option value='"+ value.id_tarifa +"'>"+ value.desc_tar +"</option>";
  }

 });
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que si coincide con el id ponerlo al inicio de mi select y los demás debajo de el.

Este es mi objeto que recibo en JavaScript

```
(19) […]
0: Object { id_tarifa: "21", proveedor: "ALESTRAqq", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP ADICO", … }
1: Object { id_tarifa: "38", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP YAGAMI", … }
2: Object { id_tarifa: "24", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP MAQUI", … }
3: Object { id_tarifa: "25", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP MIDOT", … }
4: Object { id_tarifa: "26", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP MUNDO", … }
5: Object { id_tarifa: "50", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "DG ORIENTACIÓN VOCACIONAL", … }
6: Object { id_tarifa: "35", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP SSEGUROS", … }
7: Object { id_tarifa: "42", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP KEPLER", … }
8: Object { id_tarifa: "68", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP ALPHAUSA", … }
9: Object { id_tarifa: "55", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP PLATAFORMA", … }
10: Object { id_tarifa: "57", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP THK MEXICO", … }
11: Object { id_tarifa: "58", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP EUREST", … }
12: Object { id_tarifa: "60", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP SAYTI", … }
13: Object { id_tarifa: "61", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP ARKADIA", … }
14: Object { id_tarifa: "67", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP DONAPOYO", … }
15: Object { id_tarifa: "64", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "corp_lomas", … }
16: Object { id_tarifa: "65", proveedor: "ALESTRA", desc_tar: "PHARMADERMIC-COSMETICS", … }
17: Object { id_tarifa: "70", proveedor: "0", desc_tar: "0", … }
18: Object { id_tarifa: "71", proveedor: "asd", desc_tar: "das", … }
length: 19
<prototype>: Array []
```

Comment: y si publicas tu objeto para saber la estructura?

Comment: Listo, ya publique la estructura del arreglo

Comment: para qué quieres que esté al inicio? o solo quieres que este seleccionado por default?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tengo un id_tarifa que obtengo de una consulta por ejemplo id_tarifa = 64 esa tarifa es la que aplica para un paquete que selecciono un cliente entonces cuando quiero editar quiero que salga al inicio la tarifa que pertenece a ese cliente y los restantes abajo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas jquery, puedes usar [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) para eliminarlo de donde está y [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/unshift) para insertarlo al principio.

```js
function alPrincipio(arr, index) {
  const value = arr.splice(index, 1);
  arr.unshift(value[0]);
}

const tarifas = [{
    id_tarifa: "21",
    proveedor: "ALESTRAqq",
    desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP ADICO"
  },
  {
    id_tarifa: "38",
    proveedor: "ALESTRA",
    desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP YAGAMI"
  },
  {
    id_tarifa: "24",
    proveedor: "ALESTRA",
    desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP MAQUI"
  },
  {
    id_tarifa: "25",
    proveedor: "ALESTRA",
    desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP MIDOT"
  },
  {
    id_tarifa: "26",
    proveedor: "ALESTRA",
    desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP MUNDO"
  }, {
    id_tarifa: "50",
    proveedor: "ALESTRA",
    desc_tar: "DG ORIENTACIÓN VOCACIONAL"
  },
  {
    id_tarifa: "35",
    proveedor: "ALESTRA",
    desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP SSEGUROS"
  },
  {
    id_tarifa: "42",
    proveedor: "ALESTRA",
    desc_tar: "TRONCALES SIP KEPLER"
  }
];

alPrincipio(tarifas, 2)

console.log(tarifas)
```